# Why is my Google request denied?

Tags: rest-api, webservices, integration, json, httprequest

I am trying to integrate Salesforce with Google textsearch in order to acquire a JSON response with desired information.  My request is getting denied and I can't figure out why.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
httprequest req = new httprequest();
        http http = new http();
        req.setmethod('GET');

        string url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json'
            + '?query=' + name + '+'
            + city + '+'
            + state + '+'
            + zipcode
            + '&Key={MY-API-KEY}';
        req.setEndpoint(url);

        HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
        system.debug(resp.getbody());
        string jsonResults = resp.getbody();
```

The response from this request is:

07:44:31.155 (155112095)|USER_DEBUG|[105]|DEBUG|{
   "error_message" : "An internal error was found for this API project.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: Google gets spammed with requests coming from same IP pool (Salesforce servers). Do you really have a valid key in your request and have you by any chance exhausted your daily quota? I did a mixed geocoding demo (client & server-side) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122038/how-do-i-integrate-salesforce-with-google-maps, with client-side geocoding it'd use your IP instead of SF IP

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Comment: @eyescream Thanks for the quick reply.  The Places API is enabled in Google and the key is valid.  Quota has not been met as I am making but a few requests daily.  I have a geocoding API already in place that successfully gets lat and lng.  I want to replace geocode api with place search api.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/faq#why_do_i_keep_receiving_status_request_denied ? Maybe the `key` should be lowercase... It's not exactly a SF question (because looks like callout succeeds, remote site settings are ok etc), there are few similar ones on StackOverflow or on code.google.com boards.

Comment: It worked!  My other API has a capital 'K' as well and it works just fine.  I am making them all lower case for uniformity.  I copied the request from my other api and never thought to change 'Key' to 'key'.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out the problem was in this line of code:

- '&Key={MY-API-KEY}';

Instead of using 'Key' I used 'key' and it worked.